# How to fix 'EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)' crash in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

I am trying to fix a bug that I am not able to recreate.It's random.
I've tried many ways, but this bug is still here.what should i do?

Can anybody help me how can i fix this my issue.

This is the full stack trace.It's too long.
From the release version log,this crash mostly occurs on iOS 12.

> Date/Time:           2019-03-30 14:05:08.7487 +0800
>
> Launch Time:         2019-03-30 14:04:56.2126 +0800
>
> OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.2 (16E227)
>
> Baseband Version:    1.04.30
>
> Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Triggered by Thread:  13
>
> Application Specific Information:
>
> abort() called

```
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b18c78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f1f320 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19fc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   GraphicsServices                0x00000001a6155dd4 GSEventRunModal + 108
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d0e7000c UIApplicationMain + 216
6   qipeishangBeta                  0x00000001014feaec 0x100da4000 + 7711468
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a39d8ffc start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b23ec4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a312c998 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 31128 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
2   qipeishangBeta                  0x0000000101a0d1b0 0x100da4000 + 13013424
3   qipeishangBeta                  0x000000010187f594 0x100da4000 + 11384212
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a0374 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a18f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a8e2c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 552
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a9970 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 364
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39b1d18 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9bab0 _pthread_wqthread + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dc4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b23ec4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a312c998 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 31128 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
2   qipeishangBeta                  0x0000000101a0d1b0 0x100da4000 + 13013424
3   qipeishangBeta                  0x000000010187f594 0x100da4000 + 11384212
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a0374 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a18f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a8e2c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 552
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a9970 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 364
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39b1d18 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9bab0 _pthread_wqthread + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dc4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b18c78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f1f320 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19fc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f957c -[NSRunLoop+ 34172 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a4935e70 -[NSRunLoop+ 282224 (NSRunLoop) run] + 92
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f8184 -[NSThread main] + 72
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a4a2e040 __NSThread__start__ + 988
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b99920 _pthread_body + 132
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9987c _pthread_start + 48
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b23ec4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a312c998 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 31128 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
2   qipeishangBeta                  0x0000000101a0d1b0 0x100da4000 + 13013424
3   qipeishangBeta                  0x000000010187f594 0x100da4000 + 11384212
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a0374 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a18f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a8e2c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 552
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a9970 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 364
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39b1d18 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9bab0 _pthread_wqthread + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dc4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b18c78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f1f320 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19fc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f957c -[NSRunLoop+ 34172 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f9404 -[NSRunLoop+ 33796 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 100
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d0f5ba40 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 140
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f8184 -[NSThread main] + 72
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a4a2e040 __NSThread__start__ + 988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b99920 _pthread_body + 132
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9987c _pthread_start + 48
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b23ec4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a312c998 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 31128 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
2   qipeishangBeta                  0x0000000101a0d1b0 0x100da4000 + 13013424
3   qipeishangBeta                  0x000000010187f594 0x100da4000 + 11384212
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a0374 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a18f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a8e2c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 552
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a9970 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 364
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39b1d18 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9bab0 _pthread_wqthread + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dc4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b23ec4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a312ca34 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait+ 31284 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 100
2   qipeishangBeta                  0x0000000101a0f6bc 0x100da4000 + 13022908
3   qipeishangBeta                  0x0000000101a0f170 0x100da4000 + 13021552
4   qipeishangBeta                  0x000000010187f594 0x100da4000 + 11384212
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a0374 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a18f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a8e2c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 552
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a9970 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 364
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39b1d18 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9bab0 _pthread_wqthread + 308
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dc4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b18c78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f1f320 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19fc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   CFNetwork                       0x00000001a453b2bc -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 220
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f8184 -[NSThread main] + 72
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a4a2e040 __NSThread__start__ + 988
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b99920 _pthread_body + 132
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9987c _pthread_start + 48
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  msfthread
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b18c78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f1f320 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19fc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f957c -[NSRunLoop+ 34172 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
5   qipeishangBeta                  0x0000000101c8a358 0x100da4000 + 15623000
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f8184 -[NSThread main] + 72
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a4a2e040 __NSThread__start__ + 988
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b99920 _pthread_body + 132
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9987c _pthread_start + 48
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  msfsafethread
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b18c78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f1f320 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19fc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f957c -[NSRunLoop+ 34172 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a4935e70 -[NSRunLoop+ 282224 (NSRunLoop) run] + 92
6   qipeishangBeta                  0x0000000101c8c87c 0x100da4000 + 15632508
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f8184 -[NSThread main] + 72
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a4a2e040 __NSThread__start__ + 988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b99920 _pthread_body + 132
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9987c _pthread_start + 48
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  GCDAsyncSocket-CFStream
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b18c78 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f1f320 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19fc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1344
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f19764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f957c -[NSRunLoop+ 34172 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
5   qipeishangBeta                  0x00000001017b4f14 0x100da4000 + 10555156
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a48f8184 -[NSThread main] + 72
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a4a2e040 __NSThread__start__ + 988
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b99920 _pthread_body + 132
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9987c _pthread_start + 48
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b24308 __select + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b99920 _pthread_body + 132
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9987c _pthread_start + 48
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dcc thread_start + 4

Thread 13 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b240bc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a3a7d250 __abort + 156
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a3a7d1b4 __abort + 0
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001a3b78c84 _malloc_put + 0
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001a3b78e4c malloc_report + 64
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001a3b6a528 free + 432
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f3d6a0 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 10412
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f3e654 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 140
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a3f3e700 CFStringCreateWithFormat + 48
9   libnetwork.dylib                0x00000001a4fed57c -[NWConcrete_nw_association redactedDescription] + 96
10  Foundation                      0x00000001a4a10e4c _NS_os_log_callback + 188
11  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001a3bb5f34 _os_log_fmt_flatten_NSCF + 64
12  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001a3bb5478 _os_log_fmt_flatten_data + 204
13  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001a3bbbdf4 _os_log_impl_flatten_and_send + 1644
14  libnetwork.dylib                0x00000001a4fef1cc __nw_association_schedule_deactivation_block_invoke + 316
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a18f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39a48f0 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 408
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39b4b50 _dispatch_source_invoke2 + 892
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39b44f4 _dispatch_source_invoke + 432
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39aaba8 _dispatch_workloop_invoke2 + 636
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39aa67c _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 428
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a39b1d18 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9bab0 _pthread_wqthread + 308
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dc4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 16 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a3b23ec4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a312c998 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 31128 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001ab20414c void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >+ 573772 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 104
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001ab208190 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop+ 590224 () + 172
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001ab20792c bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger+ 588076 (std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 0
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001ab209344 std::__1::__thread_specific_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct>::set_pointer+ 594756 (std::__1::__thread_struct*) + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b99920 _pthread_body + 132
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3b9987c _pthread_start + 48
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a3ba1dcc thread_start + 4
```

Comment: is this the full stack trace or you have trimmed the below part

Comment: @sanjaykmwt not full stack trace

Comment: need full stack trace bro please edit the question

Comment: @sanjaykmwt I post full stack trace now.

Comment: are you doing some string operation like append string or create string with format

Answer (score 0):

It seems abort get called due to exception, may be because you are passing bad data  to a system routine and the routine is saying that it's bad and can't continue, so it's killing your app.

Comment: lool like this.but how to find it?